# Can not get couch to recognize _fti

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-lucene

I've got this in my couchdb local.ini. I know it's in ok because I see it in httpd_global_handlers config in futon.

_fti = {couch_httpd_proxy, handle_proxy_req, <<"http://127.0.0.1:5985">>}

Lucene is running ok.

Yet when I try to access _fti through couch i'm getting this ...

http://localhost:5984/myDbName/_fti
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}

Comment: Have you restarted your instance after you changed the local.ini

Comment: Yes. I did restart my instance, but did not work. It actually worked after changing the port in the local.ini file. But could not figure out Why.

Comment: You can always go directly to the configuration view(_config). If it's not working and you are using the same URL as mentioned, then the problem could be a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This path is when you are using the Python hook script. But you are adding a proxy handler which you query like `http://localhost:5984/_fti/local/myDbName/_design/foo/by_content?q=hello`